# How to resolve overlapping instance

Tags: haskell

I have the following code (transform is similar to convert)

```
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Transformable a a where
  transform x = x

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (Transformable l l',   Transformable r r' )
         => Transformable (Either l r) (Either l' r')
  where
    transform = bimap transform transform
```

Of course, those instances overlap in the case where I'm trying to transform `Either a b` to `Either a b` and get the following error message (`ParsingError` is a type alias for `Either something somethingElse`)

```
    Overlapping instances for Transformable
                                (parsingerror text) (parsingerror text)
      arising from a use of ‘makereceipt’
    matching instances:
Matching instances:    Overlapping instances for Transformable
                            (ParsingError Text) (ParsingError Text)
  arising from a use of ‘makeReceipt’
Matching instances:
  instance [overlappable] (Transformable l l', Transformable r r') =>
                          Transformable (Either l r) (Either l' r')
      instance [overlappable] (Transformable l l', Transformable r r') =>
                              Transformable (Either l r) (Either l' r')
        -- Defined at Handler/GLEnterReceiptSheet/ReceiptRow.hs:154:31
      instance [overlap ok] Transformable a a
        -- Defined at Handler/GLEnterReceiptSheet/ReceiptRow.hs:151:27
```

I tried different combination of `OVERLAPS`, `OVERLAPPING` and `OVERLAPPABLE` but nothing works. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will have to change one of the instance definitions:

```
class Transformable a b where 
  transform :: a -> b 

-- this one
instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} (a ~ b) => Transformable a b where
  transform x = x

instance (Transformable l l', Transformable r r' )
       => Transformable (Either l r) (Either l' r') where
  transform = either (Left . transform) (Right . transform) 

test0 :: (Transformable a a', Transformable b b') => Either a b -> Either a' b'
test0 = transform
```

And the code will work regardless of which overlap you use on the other instance. You don't actually need any pragma on the second instance.

The problem with the original code is that the instances are actually *incoherent*, not just overlapping, so no combination of `{-# OVERLAPS / OVERLAPPING / OVERLAPPABLE #-}` would save you - you would need to use `{-# INCOHERENT #-}`, which is not desirable and I wouldn't recommend it. GHC will tell you about this incoherence with the error message:

```
>:t transform :: (Transformable a a', Transformable b b') => Either a b -> Either a' b'

<interactive>:1:1: Warning:
    Overlapping instances for Transformable
                                (Either a1 b1) (Either a'1 b'1)
      arising from a use of `transform'
    Matching instances:
      instance [overlappable] (Transformable l l', Transformable r r') =>
                              Transformable (Either l r) (Either l' r')
        -- Defined at test6.hs:9:31
      instance [overlap ok] Transformable a a -- Defined at test6.hs:6:27
    (The choice depends on the instantiation of `a1, b1, a'1, b'1'
     To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
     when compiling the other instance declarations)
    In the expression:
        transform ::
          (Transformable a a', Transformable b b') =>
          Either a b -> Either a' b'
```

Essentially, in order to pick from overlapping instances, one instance must be "most specific" for the type(s) you are trying to match. The details of this are given in the [user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#overlapping-instances).

Comment: I tried to read the user guide but I don't understand anything. Could you explain the difference between `Transformable a a` and `a ~ b => Transformable a b`  and why one is incorherent whereas the other is ok. They look the same for me.

Comment: @mb14, the complexity of the documentation for `OverlappingInstances` is one of the things that convinced me it's a bad idea. Since then I've seen a good bit of evidence that it's "intrusive", breaking all sorts of otherwise good intuition. I'm really not a fan at all.

Comment: @dfeur I agree, however in that case I don't really have the choice. The most annoying is that those overlapping instances have in fact the implementation, so in practice there is no overlap. Also, I wouldn't have this problem if I could add an inequality constraint on the Either instance.

Comment: The instance `(a ~ b) => Transformable a b` is not incoherent because it is always less specific than the other one, regardless of instantiation of type variables. @dfeuer I agree that the new overlapping instances machinery is confusing at the very least. In many cases you can save yourself the headache by just not using them, but I don't have enough information about the actual problem to see how that could be done here.

Comment: Using 'instance  {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} a ~ b => ...` worked.