# Haskell: instances parameterized type one single type

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

I'm writing some parser code, which involves a parameterized type:

```hs
data Power i    = Power1 { charges :: i } | Power2 { charges :: i }
```

Where I know the type `i` will always be an `Int` (but is parameterized because I need it for another type class).
Now I want to make my `Power` type derive from `Show` (in a specific formatting, so I need to override it myself). As I know that `i` will only ever be `Int`, I tried:

```hs
instance Show (Power Int) where
    show (Power1 0)    = ""
    show (Power1 i)    = "some formatting involving i\n"
    show (Power2 0)    = ""
    show (Power2 i)    = "some other formatting involving i\n"
```

However, this won't compile, with the message

```
    • Illegal instance declaration for ‘Show (Power Int)’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Show (Power Int)’
   |
22 | instance Show (Power Int) where
```

Why isn't this possible?

Why is this so different to the compiler than?

```hs
instance (Show i) => Show (Power i) where
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHC says `All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an) where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*`. That is defined in [Haskell 98](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-FlexibleInstances). To take data type with a concrete type as class parameter require `FlexibleInstances` extension. Because there is overwrapping instances problem.

For example:

```hs
newtype Foo a = Foo a

class Bar a where
    baz :: a -> a

instance Bar (Foo Int) where
    baz = ...

instance Show a => Bar (Foo a) where
    baz = ...
```

When you call `baz 1`, compiler confuses whether version should call. `1` is `Int` but also belongs `Show` class! Details written in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36913922/how-to-resolve-overlapping-instance), you should read it when you have time.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use type constraints with Types, but with Type classes. In your example, it is possible to instantiate Show for the `Integral` type class. Then show is defined for `Power Int` and `Power Integer`.

```
instance Integral a => Show (Power a) where
    show (Power1 0)    = ""
    show (Power1 i)    = "some formatting involving i\n"
    show (Power2 0)    = ""
    show (Power2 i)    = "some other formatting involving i\n"
```